# webgl-surface-plot: Clips at Different Rotations

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d

I am trying to use webgl-surface-plot to give a 3D surface plot of data.  At several orientations, the axes labels get clipped.  At other orientations, part of the graph gets clipped.  Is there a way to expand the canvas size and/or move the axes labels closer to the axes?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default scale/zoom in the code and then just increase the canvas dimensions via the input options. I plan to add the starting zoom as an option to the chart, when I get a chance. I want to fix the axis labels as well. Currently they are at a fixed distance from the axes. They should, instead, be at a distance dictated by the length of the tick labels. Fixing this will be quite tricky, though.